# Error Code after moving subsite through Content and Structure

Tags: content-type, content-and-structure

SharePoint 2013 - I have a site collection that has a lot of subsites.  In effort to organize, I created a subsite to house several of the other subsites and moved them using "Content and Structure".  Now when I try to add a content type to the workflow tasks in the subsites that I moved, I get the "Sorry something went wrong error."  Suggestions on how to fix?  TIA!